# How to drop table in Xamarin from sqlite database

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, sqlite, xamarin

I am unable to drop tables completely from sqLite database in XAMARIN using command `db.DropTable<tablename>`. It gets dropped at first but appears again every time I restart the application. Also I have multiple tables with the same name and I need to drop them all. What should I do?

I am developing an android application in Visual Studio using XAMARIN and C#.

Unfortunately I created many tables with the same name. Now I need to drop them.

I am using following code to create tables and database:-

```
namespace Test
{
[Table("OrderDetails")]
public class OrderDetails
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement, Column("_id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string payeename { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string commodity { get; set; }

    public int give { get; set; }

    public int take { get; set; }
    public DateTime date { get; set; }
}

[Activity(Label = "Test", MainLauncher = true)]
public class MainActivity : Activity
{

    [Table("Items")]
    public class PayeeMaster
    {
        [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement, Column("_id")]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(8)]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(8)]
        public string LastName { get; set; }
    }
    SQLiteConnection db;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

        CreateDatabase();



    }


   public bool ifExists_Table(string tablename)
    {



        SQLiteCommand command = db.CreateCommand("SELECT COUNT(1) FROM SQLITE_MASTER WHERE TYPE = @TYPE AND NAME = @NAME");
        command.Bind("@TYPE", "table");
        command.Bind("@NAME", tablename);

        int result = command.ExecuteQuery<int>();
        return (result > 0);


    }

  public void CreateDatabase() {
     try
     {  
            string dbPath = Path.Combine(

System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal),
            "Master.db3");

            db = new SQLiteConnection(dbPath);

        }
        catch (IOException ex)
        {
            var reason = string.Format("The database failed to create - 
     reason {0}", ex.Message);

        }



            if (!ifExists_Table("PayeeMaster"))
            {

                db.CreateTable<PayeeMaster>();
            }

            else
            {
                var count = db.Table<PayeeMaster>().Count();

            }



        if (!ifExists_Table("OrderDetails"))
            {

                db.CreateTable<OrderDetails>();
            }

            else {
                var count = db.Table<OrderDetails>().Count();
            }


     }
 }
```

Comment: Could you post some source code of how you are using the database? Isn't it possible that you are creating the tables after first connection? Or how do the tables come into existence in the first place?

Comment: I have added my code.Please check

Comment: And which tables are you dropping at runtime? In the code you are clearly creating the payeemaster table at launch

Comment: Dropping the same table i.e. PayeeMaster (Added Code for the same).
But it appears again after restarting the application

Comment: Because you are creating it again :-D! See - `if (db.Table<PayeeMaster>().Count() ==0) db.CreateTable<PayeeMaster>();` ⬅️⬅️⬅️

Comment: That's the point . I am creating a new table after dropping but at runtime I find two tables with the same name ; one I dropped earlier and one I created again. Doing this I have 14 tables with the same name and none has dropped completely from database.

Answer (score 0):

I finally understand the problem, sorry for the confusion.

First of all - doing `Table<T>().Count()` doesn't actually check for table existence, but instead checks if the table contains any rows.

To actually check if the table exists, you will have to do an actual SQL query:

```
private bool DoesTableExist(string name)
{
    SQLiteCommand command = _connection.CreateCommand("SELECT COUNT(1) FROM SQLITE_MASTER WHERE TYPE = @TYPE AND NAME = @NAME");
    command.Bind("@TYPE", "table");
    command.Bind("@NAME", name);

    int result = command.ExecuteScalar<int>();
    return (result > 0);
}
```

Comment: I am getting zero as the value of result while the table still exists in the database.

Comment: Is there anything missing?

Comment: That is really weird :-O ! Could you upload the sqlite database with the two same tables somewhere? I really would like to see where the problem is

Comment: I would prefer the sqlite file itself, could you post it somewhere?

Comment: Where can I find that sqlite file ? Is there a standard path where it is stored

Comment: It should be in `%UserProfile%\AppData\Local\Packages\{Yourappname_someID}`. In this folder you should find all data of your app, and the db will likely be in `LocalState` folder

Comment: Unable to find folder for my application. Packages only contain system apps folder of windows

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn't realize your app is Android, not UWP. I think you should be able to follow this walkthrough to access the app files - https://xamarinhelp.com/accessing-files-emulators/